# Clearfix in Edge (Windows 10)?

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

How do I make an "old-fashioned" clearfix in Edge? It seems not to work the same way as all other browser? Or is it? I read you should use `display:flow-root` but I as I understand it does not work exactly the same way (https://codepen.io/thierry/pen/GrvWNM).

So **is there an option for the Edge-"experience" to work the same way as all other browsers regarding to clearfix**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to check your codepen example in Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0 and Google Chrome browser and I found that both are giving the similar results.

You can also try to refer an example below for clearfix which is working fine in Edge and other browsers.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
  border: 3px solid #4CAF50;
  padding: 5px;
}

.clearfix {
  overflow: auto;
}

.img2 {
  float: right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="clearfix">
  <img class="img2" src="https://i.postimg.cc/1txjfPHb/pineapple.jpg" alt="Pineapple" width="170" height="170">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum...
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Output in MS Edge:

[image]

Reference:

(1) [How TO - Clear Floats (Clearfix)](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_clearfix.asp)

Comment: Thanks for putting me in right direction. I did not have overflow:auto; on my clearfix class and when putting it there it worked. Thank you a lot! (Now I use clear: both;    content: "";    display: block; overflow:auto;)